# Avoiding mysql General error: 1366 Incorrect string value

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, utf-8, character-encoding

When inserting a value into my DB I got the mysql error:

```
General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xE4ngen....' for ....
```

I'm using zend framework 1.10 with PDO and the data I'm trying to insert is parsed from an XML file in UTF8. Mysql is 5.6.14.

I've also checked my mysql database, table and column collations and they are:

- database: latin1_general_ci
- table: utf8_unicode_ci
- column: utf8_unicode_ci

As my input comes from an XML file I ran iconv to check if the file is valid utf8: iconv -f UTF-8 file -o /dev/null and everything looks fine but I can't really trust this XML because it comes from an external source that I don't control.

What I really want is a safe way to deal with this so that the data is imported into MySQL in case everything is UTF8 OK and in case it has some encoding problem... How can I make a "bullet-proof" way to read this data in PHP and insert into mysql?

Comment: Is throwing an exception a solution? Or do you need to fix the wrong encoding by all means?

Comment: Exactly: I need to fix it by all means. As I can't trust the source to not make mistakes and some sources are OK and some aren't I really have to bullet proof my code, even if the data imported has some problems with "weird chars" appearing, it still is better than today where the data isn't imported.

Comment: Well, then I don't envy you. Detecting arbitrary encodings – and then also converting them properly – is \*cough* a lot of fun.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't trust the input being in any particular character encoding you are pretty much forced to treat it as arbitrary binary data. Convert the column to a `BLOB`, `VARBINARY` or `BINARY` data type.